# Changing the value of a variable based on conditional logic

Tags: php

I'm trying to change the contents of an array based on the selection of checkboxes.

I have a form that contains:

```
    <div class="filter-item">
            <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $table_type->term_id; ?>" name="table_type[]" />
            <label for="<?php echo $table_type->slug; ?>"><?php echo $table_type->name; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-item">
        <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $model->term_id; ?>" name="model[]" />
        <label for="<?php echo $model->slug; ?>"><?php echo $model->name; ?></label>
    </div>
```

And I'm constructing the arrays like so:

```
    if(isset($_POST['table_type']) && $_POST['table_type']) {
        $filter = $_POST['table_type'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['model']) && $_POST['model']) {
        $filter = $_POST['model'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['table_type']) && $_POST['table_type'] && isset($_POST['model']) && $_POST['model']) {
        $filter = array_merge($_POST['table_type'], $_POST['model']);
    }
```

The above works great when only one filter type is selected i.e. table_type for example. However, when two or more are selected I think the $filter array is outputted three times as each if statement is true.
What can I do here to make this work better?

UPDATE:
I've know got the multiple arrays feeding in to one.
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 138 [1] => 139 [2] => 140 [3] => 155 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 150 [1] => 149 [2] => 154 [3] => 151 ) )`

The problem I have now is that it has an array in side of an array for each field type. How can I make this one continuous array with the values only?

Comment: All those `&&`s are redundant btw

Comment: Why are they redundant @ADyson?

Comment: Anyway you need to add to the array gradually depending on what's selected, rather than overwriting it in each case

Comment: They're redundant because isset() is already doing what you need. Checking that the value is truthy doesn't achieve anything extra beyond that.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['table_type']))` and `if ($_POST['table_type'])` are, more or less, equivalent. You cannot get a true boolean `FALSE` in a posted variable. I would only use `isset()`.

Comment: I have removed the && and am now using just isset().

Comment: @ADyson how would I go about adding to the array gradually?

Comment: Well to give you an exact example it would help to know what kind of structure you need $filter to have? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: Maybe it should be an array of arrays perhaps?

Comment: I am passing the variable $filter in to a WordPress meta query to get posts with an ID in the array.

Comment: Ok. But I don't know what structure that function requires inside the variable. You need to be specific. Give an example.

Comment: @ADyson please see the updated post.

Comment: If you make it a continuous array though, how is the code which receives it going to know which value is for filtering which field? Also, as it stands, you're likely to get duplicate keys. Are you sure that's the format which is needed? You mentioned it's a wordpress function that you're sending this to...is there some documentation online you can give us a link to?

Comment: The fields are ALL based on the ID. It's irrelevant of the type. I just need one array with all of the IDs in, not array(array()).

Comment: That really doesn't make sense as far as I can see. Surely you need to know which field you're filtering. But anyway, have it your way. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php is likely what you need